# Should I expect adding more RAM of the same model to lead to worse benchmarks?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, performance, amd-ryzen

I bought 4 2x16GB Corsair Vengeance 3200 LPX kits thinking this would be the same as buying 1 128GB kit. I seemed to have lucked out in that my motherboard (ASRock x399 Fatal1ty) can use all 128GB at close to the rated clock speeds (all this despite the memory not being listed on the manufacturer's compatibility list).

When I was running benchmarks with Passmark, I discovered my RAM read/write speeds and latency got nontrivially worse as I added more RAM. With dual channel 32GB, I was on the high end of AMD machines for that RAM model (2400 passmark score; 20k MB/s uncached read); for quad channel 64GB and 128GB, the low end (sub 2100; 14k MB/s uncached read). I was a little surprised by this.

I'm trying to decide if I should return it and get a 128GB kit (e.g. Vengeance LPX 3000).

- Should I expect benchmarks to fall simply because I added more RAM (i.e. would 32GB from a 128GB kit be expected to benchmark better than all 128GB)?
- Could it be related to the fact that I'm running 4x32GB kits as a 128GB one? (i.e. are larger kits fundamentally engineered differently? I had assumed the differences were primarily packaging and guarantees they were from the same manufacturing batch)
- Are kits and motherboard manufacturer compatibility charts primarily just guarantees the RAM works at all, or are there likely nontrivial performance gains to be had with a "correct"/supported RAM setup?

Comment: What model of memory did you replace? Have you confirmed all the timing and voltage settings are correct in the BIOS?

Comment: The only memory I've ever used in this machine is is CMK32GX4M2B3200C16. I had some stability issues running at 3200, but passes Memtest at 3133 using the default XMP profile.

Comment: If you’re having “stability” issues then that is what you need to work out before being concerned about performance ratings. Your memory should be running at the manufacturer specified settings. If it’s not, then of course it is going to benchmark differently than other RAM you were using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I bought 4 2x16GB Corsair Vengeance 3200 LPX kits thinking this would be the same as buying 1 128GB kit.

Considering the Corsair Vengeance 3200 modules in the 2x16 GB kit and the 128 GB kit are identical your assumption was correct.

> When I was running benchmarks with Passmark, I discovered my RAM read/write speeds and latency got nontrivially worse as I added more RAM. With dual channel 32GB, I was on the high end of AMD machines for that RAM model (2400 PassMark score); for quad channel 64GB and 128GB, the low end (sub 2100). I was a little surprised by this.

You should verify you were not in a mixed memory channel configuration.  In reality outside of benchmarks, you will see little improvement between small frequencies differences.

> I'm trying to decide if I should return it and get a 128GB kit (e.g. Vengeance LPX 3000).

You are welcome to do that, but there isn't a performance difference, considering the physical modules are identical.  The only difference would be the serial numbers would be incremental with one another.

> Could it be related to the fact that I'm running 4x32GB kits as a 128GB one? (i.e. are larger kits fundamentally engineered differently? I had assumed the differences were primarily packaging and guarantees they were from the same manufacturing batch)

The only differences are indeed packaging, manufacturing batch, and price.  It is basically the difference between the huge bag of potato chips, or the combo pack of potato chips, which contains two smaller bags.

> Are kits and motherboard manufacturer compatibility charts primarily just guarantee the RAM works at all, or are there likely nontrivial performance gains to be had with a "correct"/supported RAM setup?

The compatibility list is simply the list of modules that were tested.  It should be used as a guideline to find modules that are compatible (compatible frequency for example).  DDR4 is a standard, so a module running at a certain frequency and timing is going to perform nearly identical to another similar DDR4 module.  Other properties of the module that are not part of the standard (what type of heatsink it might have) are the only major differences between modules produced from difference companies.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "mixed memory channel configuration"? I just want to better understand why my uncached read would be so much slower with more memory in a quad channel config.

Comment: If you were in a configuration between dual and triple and/or quad you might see a performance hit.  Check your motherboard manual for dual/triple/quad memory channel configuration is exactly.

Comment: Yes, the RAM is in the correct slots for quad channel, and I've confirmed it is running in quad on CPU-Z. So is it a weakness of the CPU then (Ryzen 1920x) and I'll probably see the same losses with any other RAM? Could it be related to NUMA?

Comment: @Tahlor - I know the early generation(s) of Ryzen are extreemly sensitive with regard to memory compatability (frequency and timing).  I could not personally speak to any specifics with regards to different memory channel configurations with regards to Ryzen hardware though.

Comment: OK. So if it's running stable/without errors at ~3100 mhz, probably whatever read/write speeds I see with that RAM module with those settings are similar to any other similarly spec'd RAM on my hardware.